# Counting Continuous Appearances in a data table in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as given below. For each gvkey, I want to count the continuous appearances of a given Au (tenure of AU) over years. An example data frame with desired results in column called TENURE is given below:

```
 GVKEY FYEAR AU TENURE
1   1012  2000  1      1
2   1012  2001  1      2
3   1012  2002  1      3
4   1012  2003  1      4
5   1012  2004  2      1
6   1012  2005  2      2
7   1012  2006  1      1
8   1012  2007  2      1
9   1012  2008  2      2
10  1012  2009  2      3
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I am struggling with this one. Thanks.

```
> dput(head(pp,200))
structure(list(GVKEY = c(1001L, 1001L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1007L, 1007L, 1008L, 1008L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 
1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 
1012L, 1012L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1015L, 1015L, 1015L, 1015L, 1016L, 1016L, 1016L, 
1016L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 
1017L, 1017L, 1017L, 1018L, 1018L, 1018L, 1018L, 1019L, 1019L, 
1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 
1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1019L, 1020L, 1020L, 
1020L, 1020L, 1020L, 1020L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 
1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 
1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 1021L, 
1021L, 1021L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1023L, 1025L, 1025L, 1025L, 
1025L, 1025L, 1025L, 1025L, 1025L), FYEAR = c(1984L, 1985L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1984L, 1985L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 
1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 
1987L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L), AU = c(6, 
6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, -1, 5, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 20, 20, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 21, 21, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
21, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 3, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11)), .Names = c("GVKEY", 
"FYEAR", "AU"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 
142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 
153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, are you using `data.frames` or `data.tables`? Your title and your post seem to mean different things. Also please tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sequence` and `rle`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(pp)
DT[, TENURE := sequence(rle(AU)$length), by=GVKEY]

#     GVKEY FYEAR AU TENURE
#  1:  1001  1984  6      1
#  2:  1001  1985  6      2
#  3:  1003  1984  8      1
#  4:  1003  1985  8      2
#  5:  1003  1986  8      3
# ---                      
#196:  1025  1987  9      1
#197:  1025  1988 11      1
#198:  1025  1989 11      2
#199:  1025  1990 11      3
#200:  1025  1991 11      4
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
df$TENURE <- ave(df$AU, df$AU, FUN=order)
```